How to update Azure Notification Hub registration on Xamarin Forms [Android] to FCMv1
I have a Xamarin Forms application (Android app) and I know I have to migrate to FCMv1 protocol to send notifications to devices, I had read this article from Microsoft about migration, but is not clear to me how to tell my xamarin android app to register itself as FCMv1 registration. The code I have now looks like this:
[Service(Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMessagingService";
NotificationHub hub;

public override void OnNewToken(string p0)
{
    base.OnNewToken(p0);
    SendRegistrationToServer(p0);
}

private void SendRegistrationToServer(string token)
{
    // Register with Notification Hubs
    hub = new NotificationHub(Helpers.ApiKeys.NotificationHubName, Helpers.ApiKeys.ListenConnectionString, this);
    try
    {
        hub.UnregisterAll(token);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(TAG, ex.Message);
    }

    var tags = new List<string>() { Entities.Settings.DeviceId };
    var regID = hub.Register(token, tags.ToArray()).RegistrationId;

    Log.Debug(TAG, $"Successful registration of ID {regID}");
}
}

How I can register my application as FCMv1 ?

Are you successfully getting regID value ?

yes, but is a registration of type Fcm (legacy)
